# JUnit and concurrency: inexplicable error

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, junit

I read in a few posts that using JUnit to test concurrency is not ideal but I have no choice for now. I have just encountered an exception that I can't explain.

I run a test where, in summary:

- I submit 1000 runnables to an executor
- each runnable adds an element to a list
- I wait for the executor termination
- JUnit tells me the list only has 999 elements
- no exception is printed in the runnable catch block

**What could cause that behavior?**

Note: I only get the exception from time to time. The code has some non related stuff but I left it there in case I missed something. `XXXQuery` is an enum.

```
public void testConcurrent() throws InterruptedException {
    final int N_THREADS = 1000;
    final XXXData xxxData = new AbstractXXXDataImpl();
    final List<QueryResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    results.add(xxxData.get(XXXQuery.values()[j % XXXQuery.values().length]));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertEquals(N_THREADS, results.size());
}
```

Comment: maybe under certain situations 10s is not long enough for all 1000 threads to complete?

Comment: In the future, please provide the Exception and show which line is effected.  Thanks.

Comment: @mcfinnigan the tests completes in less than a second.

Comment: @Gray the exception is an AssertionException sent on the last line - I should have been more specific.

Comment: OH, sorry.  Missed that.  I've edited my answer to specifically address that.

Comment: @Gray No problem the arraylist was clearly the problem so you have answered the question already (can't accept until another 3 minutes!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add to the `results` `ArrayList` in your `Runnable.run()` method in multiple threads without synchronizing around it.

The assertion failed message is showing that although `N_THREADS` calls to `add()` were made, the `ArrayList` got fewer entries because of concurrency race conditions.

I would use a final array instead of a list.  Something like:

```
final QueryResult[] results = new QueryResult[N_THREADS];
for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
    ...
        public void run() {
            results[j] = data.get(Query.values()[j % Query.values().length]);
        }
```

Also, I don't quite get the `XXXQuery.values()` but I'd pull that into a variable above the loop unless it is changing.